# Bad reloc address in `.eh_frame' and collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status when compiling with MinGW

Tags: c, windows, gcc, mingw, ld

After finishing installing MinGW and GCC on my system, I decided to test it out. I wrote the following 3 files:

### complex.h

```
# ifndef hjp_complex
# define hjp_complex

typedef struct _complex
{
    double real, image;
} complex;

complex complex_add( const complex a, const complex b );
complex complex_sub( const complex a, const complex b );
complex complex_mul( const complex a, const complex b );

# endif
```

### complex.c

```
# include "complex.h"

complex complex_add( const complex a, const complex b ) {
    complex c = a;
    c.real += b.real;
    c.image += b.image;
    return c;
}

complex complex_sub( const complex a, const complex b ) {
    complex c = a;
    c.real -= b.real;
    c.image -= b.image;
    return c;
}

complex complex_mul( const complex a, const complex b ) {
    complex c = a;
    c.real = a.real * b.real - a.image * b.image;
    c.image = a.real * b.image + a.image * b.real;
    return c;
}
```

### testing.c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include "complex.h"

# define cmplx_out(t) printf( "%.2f + %.2fi\n", t.real, t.image )

int main() {
    complex x, g, h;
    x.real = 3;         h.real = 12;
    x.image = 12;       h.image = 3;
    cmplx_out( x );
    cmplx_out( h );
    return 0;
}
```

After that, compiling and executing `testing.c` worked fine:

```
C:\Users\hjpotter92\Documents\Programming>gcc testing.c

C:\Users\hjpotter92\Documents\Programming>a
3.00 + 12.00i
12.00 + 3.00i
```

Now, when testing the functions for complex number computations (new `testing.c`):

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include "complex.h"

# define cmplx_out(t) printf( "%.2f + %.2fi\n", t.real, t.image )

int main() {
    complex x, g, h;
    x.real = 3;         h.real = 12;
    x.image = 12;       h.image = 3;
    g = complex_mul( x, h );
    cmplx_out( g );
    g = complex_sub( x, h );
    cmplx_out( g );
    g = complex_add( x, h );
    cmplx_out( g );
    return 0;
}
```

And when I try to compile it:

```
C:\Users\hjpotter92\Documents\Programming>gcc testing.c
C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwD6Lqh.o:testing.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `complex_mul'
C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwD6Lqh.o:testing.c:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `complex_sub'
C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwD6Lqh.o:testing.c:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to `complex_add'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccwD6Lqh.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Referring to a few other questions, I tried a lot of combinations:

- compiling both of them

  ```
  C:\Users\hjpotter92\Documents\Programming>gcc complex.c testing.c
  C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKuURyc.o:testing.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `complex_mul'
  C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKuURyc.o:testing.c:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `complex_sub'
  C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKuURyc.o:testing.c:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to `complex_add'
  c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccKuURyc.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
  c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  ```
- creating assembled outputs and generating output using those:

  ```
  C:\Users\hjpotter92\Documents\Programming>gcc -c testing.c

  C:\Users\hjpotter92\Documents\Programming>gcc -c complex.c

  C:\Users\hjpotter92\Documents\Programming>gcc complex.o testing.o
  testing.o:testing.c:(.text+0x7e): undefined reference to `complex_mul'
  testing.o:testing.c:(.text+0xe8): undefined reference to `complex_sub'
  testing.o:testing.c:(.text+0x172): undefined reference to `complex_add'
  c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: testing.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
  c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
  collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  ```

No difference in outputs is observed on passing `-Wall` parameter.

Can someone help me regarding the issue? The program seems to be pretty straightforward and there shouldn't be any problems with compiling and executing it.

**PS**: The program works perfectly on an Arch machine:

```
archdesktop% gcc complex.c testing.c
archdesktop% ./a.out
0.00 + 153.00i
-9.00 + 9.00i
15.00 + 15.00i
```

---

GCC details:

```
C:\Users\hjpotter92\Documents\Programming>gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-mp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
```

I used `mingw-get` to install gcc.

Comment: I have no problems with your code under latest MinGW/MSYS, what is your gcc version and where are you download it?

Comment: @vitalyster Added the information to question.

Comment: please show full output of `gcc -v testing.c complex.c`

Comment: I also cannot reproduce the issue using mingw-gcc 4.8.1 installed using [mingw-get](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/Installer/mingw-get/). You might try running this in `cmd.exe` under admin. `clang.exe` on windows sometimes have issues writing the object file out to `user\*\local\temp` but this was never an issue with mingw-gcc for me. Only other thing I can think of is that there's something wrong with your mingw install. There are several mingw project variants out there, like mingw64, tdm-mingw, mingw/msys2. Try to compile with one of those and see if the build works.

Comment: @vitalyster Changing the order of files seems to have worked. `gcc -v testing.c complex.c` assembles the program. I'll paste the output to question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, [the suggestion of](/questions/27402819/bad-reloc-address-in-eh-frame-and-collect2-exe-error-ld-returned-1-exit-sta#comment43276496_27402819) using `-v` flag while compiling seems to compile the program without errors. Once I successfully compiled the program with `-v`, `gcc` isn't running into any errors with any of the methods I was trying before.

```
C:\Users\hjpotter92\Documents\Programming>gcc -v testing.c complex.c
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=mingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto --enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gmp-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/mingw --disable-bootstrap LDFLAGS=-s CFLAGS=-D_USE_32BIT_TIME_T
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/ testing.c -quiet -dumpbase testing.c -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -auxbase testing -version -o C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDBoHzE.s
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.1 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.1 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 767202a405449496e68a54c4eee91a28
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccc6ue9i.o C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDBoHzE.s
GNU assembler version 2.24 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.24
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/cc1.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/ complex.c -quiet -dumpbase complex.c -mtune=generic -march=pentiumpro -auxbase complex -version -o C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDBoHzE.s
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.1 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed
End of search list.
GNU C (GCC) version 4.8.1 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2, MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 767202a405449496e68a54c4eee91a28
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/as.exe -v -o C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPq9b2h.o C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccDBoHzE.s
GNU assembler version 2.24 (mingw32) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.24
COMPILER_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/
LIBRARY_PATH=c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib/;c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/collect2.exe -Bdynamic c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../crt2.o c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/crtbegin.o -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1 -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/lib -Lc:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../.. C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccc6ue9i.o C:\Users\HJPOTT~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccPq9b2h.o -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lmingw32 -lgcc -lgcc_eh -lmoldname -lmingwex -lmsvcrt c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/crtend.o
```